# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 (select top 1 percent A from B order by newid())
```

i want to get the random record from table B

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? And is that the complete statement or part of another?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would guess SQL Server by the use of `NEWID()` and `TOP`

Comment: i am using SQL server and i want to run the query with brackets .

Comment: Why? Just remove the brackets. `select top 1 percent A from B order by newid()` would work fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax (that is without the outer parentheses). If I substitute A and B with names from a table that I have, it works just fine. I think that it's a problem with the names that you use. I assume that you don't actually have a table named B witha field named A, so you should show the actual code that you use.

Comment: no i want to use the statment in Where condition

Comment: @jam - So show your complete statement with the problematic bit in context. To get "the random record from table B" you don't need to use it in a `WHERE` clause at all.

Answer (score 2):

USE like this...

```
select * from B where A in 
 (select top 1 percent A from B order by newid())
```

OR

```
select top 1 percent A from B order by newid()
```

Both will give you random rows every time....

**EDIT :**

[Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx)

Comment: But there's no point having the `in` at all probably. `select top 1 percent * from B order by newid()` may well be all that is needed.

Comment: @GopeshSharma: the statement *without* the IN will be a faster. So in terms of performance this is **not** the right approach.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Yeah actually, without the IN will be faster, see my Edit

Comment: It's not actually clear what the OP is trying to do. if `A` is not unique then the two will have different semantics. If `A` is unique then the `IN` could be beneficial were the other selected columns to be relatively wide then it could reduce the amount of data being sorted.